# Simple question about sockets PHP

Tags: php, sockets

Could you please tell me, what happens in this script:

```
$conn = fsockopen($server, 43);
fputs($conn, $some_string."\r\n");
```

What kind of data will be sent to the server? GET? POST? PUT? And how should I do same job with cURL? CURLOPT_whatShouldIWriteHere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an HTTP request, just a pure TCP/IP data transfer.
As such, it's neither GET nor POST nor any other HTTP verb.

Comment: Thanks. But... Can I do the same with cURL? I have to make about 30 connections in 1 time and I found curl_multi_* that gives me some kind of multithreading.

Comment: @Chvanikoff I suppose you could reproduce this using cURL's ability to do TELNET requests, but I have to admit to have never tried this.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I think I have another question that Im going to ask here on SO soon...

Answer (score 1):

It guess that sends a raw string to the server without any header. I don´t think that CURL will do the same (always send some protocol headers), but you can do the same with netcat

```
> server=192.168.1.1
> some_string=hello
> nc $server 43 <<.
$some_string
.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a tcp socket - no HTTP at all. It will simply send whatever `$some_string` contains.

If you want to use HTTP, use CURL. See the PHP docs for an example.